# Does Google implement semantic web in any of its technology or products?

Tags: semantic-web

The semantic web is prominent and future of current web as said by TimBL. So are there any google product which uses semantic web technologies?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, the Semantic Web is a fuzzy concept, and it's not always clear whether a certain technology should be considered as part of the Semantic Web or not. Google uses lots of technologies that can be considered Semantic Web technologies in its products, such as:

- [Google Knowledge Graph](http://www.google.com/insidesearch/features/search/knowledge.html)
- [Google Rich Snippets](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=99170)
- [Freebase](http://www.freebase.com/) (acquired by Google a few years ago)
- [schema.org](http://schema.org/) (developed by Google, Yahoo and Microsoft)

Google tends to somewhat avoid the Semantic Web standards originally developed at TimBL's W3C, and instead develops its own simpler versions of these standards.